# Formula for the number of naturals whose prime factors lie in a finite set $A \subset \Bbb{P}$ and that have exactly $r$ prime factors.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, natural-numbers

Let $A$ be a finite set of prime numbers.  Then the set $X_r = \{x \in \Bbb{N}: \Omega(x) = r,$ and all the primes comprising $x$ are in $A\}$.

Has size formula ?

For example:

$$
|A| = \{2,3,5,7\} \\
r = 2\\
$$

We have:

$$
 2 \cdot 2 \\
 2 \cdot 3 \\
 2 \cdot 5 \\
 2 \cdot 7 \\
 3 \cdot 3 \\
  3\cdot 5\\
 3 \cdot 7\\
  5\cdot 5 \\
  5 \cdot 7 \\
 7 \cdot 7 \\
$$

or $10$ possibilities.  Does the formula for $|X_r|$ have a closed form expression in terms of $|A|$ and $|r|$?

I currently think it's ${|A|r\choose r}$ since there are up to $r$ copies of each of $|A|$ things, and you are choosing a combination (set) of the items of size $r$.  However computing it on $|A|=4, r=2$ produces $4\cdot 3 = 12$ as an answer not $10$.

Comment: You have combinations with (possible) repetition.

Comment: @CommutativeAlgebraStudent oops, sorry misunderstood what you were asking

Comment: @PM2Ring typing that into google is not centering in on one thing called that

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be a number that you form doing this. Then
$$x=p_1^{\alpha _1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha _k},$$
where $\sum _{i=1}^k\alpha _i=r$
notice that you can treat this as a tuple $(b_1,\cdots ,b_{|A|})$ such that $b_{i}\geq 0$ and $\sum _{i=0}^{|A|}b_i=r.$ By the stars and bars method, you get
$$\binom{|A|+r-1}{|A|-1}.$$ In the case you have you are getting
$$\binom{4+2-1}{3}=\binom{5}{2}=10.$$